# Python: raw_input leaves stuff in input buffer?

Tags: python, shell

I have a python script that reads using `raw_input` and then opens a shell using `system("sh")`, e.g

```
r_input = raw_input('Enter the key\n')
system("sh")
```

I need to feed this script some binary data, which I do using print or `sys.stdout.write`, e.g.

```
python -c "import sys; sys.stdout.write('\x02\x03\x04')" | python ./input_parse.py
```

The problem is that despite that the input is read entirely, the shell exits immediately, as if it gets some leftover from the `stdin`. When I feed the script from the keyboard, it works, but I can't put binary data there, it is interpreted as string...

I tried `subprocess`, like this (but not much difference):

```
 python -c "import subprocess; process = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'input_parse.py], shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE);process.stdin.write('hi')" | python ./py_deobf_input_parse.py
```

How can I get this to work?

**Update:** I have found a solution, maybe not ideal, but worked. Basically I used the same `subprocess` model, but had to add the `\n` to the end of my input. Then I did another `process.stdin.write` to pass the command to the opened shell. I had to add asleep between them, otherwise it was exiting immediately. I still will give a credit if someone finds a nicer answer.

```
python -c "import subprocess; import time; process = subprocess.Popen(['./py_input_parse'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE); process.stdin.write('\x02\x02\x02\x02\n'); process.stdin.flush(); time.sleep(2); process.stdin.write('cat ./flag.txt \n');
```

Comment: I don't know if this can help you, but I can do the following using the shell builtin `printf`:  `printf '\x02\x03\x04' | awk '{print length($0)}'` -> `3`

Comment: Tried that and got the same behaviour

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect? The stdin of your  `input_parse.py` is the stdout of the writing script. As soon as you've read all your binary data, the stdin is finished. So calling a shell afterwards detects a closed stdin and terminates.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Do you have a suggestion how to make it work? I've tried process.wait(), but it does not help

Comment: You want the shell's `stdin` to be the terminal instead of the pipe? Try `p = subprocess.Popen(["sh"], stdin=open('/dev/tty'));` `p.wait()`

Comment: I need to send the binary string to the script first.

Comment: My suggestion doesn't affect the incoming data on the pipe and `raw_input` statement. It replaces the subsequent `system("sh")` with a `Popen` instance in which `stdin` is redirected back to the terminal. But based on your last update I don't understand why you need to run `sh`. Surely it can't be just to execute `cat`.